# Enterprise library Rewriting the Code to Save data and return value

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

Without Enterprise Data library,I am using the below code to insert some thing to DB and reading the return value from that

```
int result = 0;
using (SqlConnection myConnection = 
    new SqlConnection(AppConfiguration.ConnectionString))
{
     SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SaveUser", myConnection);
     myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", objUser.Location);

     DbParameter returnValue;
     returnValue = myCommand.CreateParameter();
     returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
     myCommand.Parameters.Add(returnValue);

     myConnection.Open();
     myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
     result = Convert.ToInt32(returnValue.Value);
     myConnection.Close();
}
```

How can i do the same in Enterprise Datalibrary ? I want to return value from the stored procedure being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do it in similar way.  "YourDb" should be defined in your config file.

```
int result = 0;

Database db = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>("YourDb");
DbCommand myCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("SaveUser");
db.AddInParameter(myCommand, "location", DbType.String, objUser.Location);
db.ExecuteNonQuery(myCommand);
result = Convert.ToInt32(db.GetParameterValue(myCommand, "returnValue"));
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. IndexOutOfRangeException is thrown when I try to get value of "returnValue" parameter.

Comment: This was marked as the answer, but did you ever get this to work? I'm doing something similar, but trying to retrieve an out parameter instead. Here's my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39985999/microsoft-practices-enterpriselibrary-data-database-addout-parameter-not-getting

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten it using an overload of ExecuteNonQuery:

```
Database db = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>("YourDb");
db.ExecuteNonQuery("SaveUser", objUser.Location);
int result = Convert.ToInt32(db.GetParameterValue(myCommand, "returnValue"));
```

where *SaveUser* is the proc name and *objUser.Location* is the input parameter

Answer (score 0):

You must add return parameter to the command object before executing the query.

```
db.AddParameter(myCommand, "returnvalue", DbType.String, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, null, DataRowVersion.Default, null);

--Execute the query here using ExecuteNonQuery

result = Convert.ToInt32(db.GetParameterValue(myCommand, "returnValue"));
```